# Does sp_droparticle @force_invalidate_snapshot=1 invalidate the entire snapshot?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

Forgive this simple SQL Server question, but if I just want to remove a single stored procedure from snapshop replication (2008 SQL Server R2), if I call sp_droparticle, will it invalidate the entire snapshot, or just the snapshot on that article?

IE, I've got a big database, and I don't want to force a full snapshot generation again, does sp_droparticle only affect the snapshot for that single object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of a snapshot is a point-in-time copy of the entire publication, so once you make a change that affects the snapshot, it's no longer valid in its entirety.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152493%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

> Dropping an article from a publication involves dropping the article and creating a new snapshot for the publication. Dropping an article invalidates the current snapshot; therefore a new snapshot must be created.

Once you call [`sp_droparticle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173832%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and invalidate the snapshot, the publication cannot be subscribed to again until a new snapshot is generated.